# Unable to extract the data through xpath or css selector

Tags: xpath, scrapy

When I do inspect element or view source, the required data is available on page, but when I extract them by using xpath or css, I am getting an empty list. Even I tried to extract all the nodes and it's content but that required data which was shown in View page source are not getting extracted. What could be the reason?
Below is the example code:
I need to extract href value from  tag.

```
<div class="url-link">
    <a data-id="abc" class="abc xyz" data-is-avod="" href="/ab/extract/xyz/3&t=25">Title</a>
    <span>title</span>
</div>
```

I used `response.xpath('//div/a/@href').extract()` xpath but I am unable to extract the desired content.

I have analyzed and found when I logged in to the website then only inspect element or View page source shows this `<a>` tag else it does not show. So i think to get the `#href` text i need to pass the form with login information, but I don't know how to pass a form and how to get details of the form.

Please help.

Comment: Show your data and what you have tried?

Comment: Should I post the website and xpath i tried ?

Comment: You need to give us a re-producible example, without linking to external resources.

Comment: I need to extract the #href text. Below eg:

<div class="url-link">
 <a data-id="abc" class="abc xyz" data-is-avod="" href="/ab/extract/xyz/3&t=25">Title</a>
 <span>title</span>
</div>
when I use xpath, response.xpath('//div/a/@href').extract() to extract the href text it gives empty list.

I just analyzed and found when I logged in to the website then only inspect element or View page source shows this <a> tag else it does not show. So i think to get the href text i need to pass the form with login information, but I don't know how to pass a form and how to get details of the form.